# Apply CSP on PrimeFaces project

Tags: primefaces

I a tryinng to apply CSP on a PrimeFaces project. I have a javascript file three.js, and i would like include it on a whitelist.

<script src="three.js" nonce="123"></script>

I already defined my web.xml

```
<context-param><!-- Enabling CSP -->
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
    
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP_POLICY</param-name>
    <param-value>script-src 'self' 'nonce-123'</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However when i do this, then i check the header Content Security Policy and i am able to see two, the default policy and the policy that include three.js to whitelist. However, it is not really added to the with list and i get the same result that i get if i just have:

```
<context-param><!-- Enabling CSP -->
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, if i just use the second statement, i means:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP_POLICY</param-name>
    <param-value>script-src 'self' 'nonce-123'</param-value>
</context-param>
```

i am not getting the header Content Security Policy.

I should be getting a header Content Security Policy and three.js should be added to the while list of CSP.

Comment: What do you mean by "SCP"?

Comment: my bad, Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the issue just adding 'unsafe-eval', however, in my opinion it should be the last option.

```html
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
    
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP_POLICY</param-name>
    <param-value>script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self' 'nonce-123'</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It would be great if somebody know a better way.

Comment: Have you tried using `<h:outputScript>` rather than raw `<script>` so PrimeFaces can add the normal `nonce` to it?  But ither way if `three.js` uses `eval` there is nothing you can do except get `three.js` to fix their code to be compliant with CSP.

Comment: I dont have problem with nonce, primefaces apply it. The problem is that unless i use 'unsafe-eval' it give more relevance to its primary policy.

Comment: Yes but that means three.js is using JS `eval` call and you will HAVE to use `unsafe-eval`